# Individual CCK Imagefield promote-to-front

Tags: views, media

At the moment, my view creates a gallery of images by fetching all images across multiple node types. What I need is a way to indicate which images should be used in the gallery. So, instead of my view simply displaying all images, I want the client to indicate which image they want to "promote" to the gallery.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option, that will work for sure.  May need to do a bit of reconfiguring with your current imagefields.

- Download latest version of CCK 3.x.
- Install multigroups module (currently this module is stable)

On the selected content type:

- Add on/off checkbox featured field (set limit to 1)
- Add Image field (set limit to 1)
- Encapsulate theses 2 fields in a multigroup (set limit to unlimited)
- Create view that will filter on featured field

Answer (score 1):

So, in my example scenario, I needed to indicate which individual image(s) are to be part of my gallery.

My node/1 contains a cck imagefield with unlimited uploads and currently holds 5 images. Of those 5, I want 2 of the images to be part of a gallery on a seperate page.

So, in the global settings of cck imagefield configuration, there is the 'list field' area with 2 radio button options. By default it is set to 'disabled'. I enabled it.
Now, in the node there will be a check box next to each one of the image uploads. I check the images I want in my gallery.

In the view that generates my gallery, in the filter area, each imagefield exposes a 'list' option for your cck imagefields. It's options are 'true' of 'false'. I make sure it is set to true.

This way I now how granular control over my image displays.

I trust that will help someone out there!

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have to add checkbox field to all content types for indicate image to promote.

Comment: As my nodes have multiple images, the checkbox will not target individual images but the entire node itself ???

Comment: I am trying to indicate individual imagefields as promoted-to-front or display this image in the gallery. Not promote the entire node and get all it's images

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options

Option 1:
In your view, you add a filter for

```
Node: Promoted to front page
Whether or not the node is promoted to the front page.
```

Set value is 1.  Now all nodes promoted to the front page will be in the gallery

Option 2:
You create a cck field that is a single on/off checkbox.  Featured Image
Go back to your view and add a filter for this new cck field.

Comment: But isn't the on/off checkbox referring to the node rather than the imagefield ?? My nodes have multiple images

Comment: yes, it would feature all images attached to that node

Comment: Did some research, and found 2 threads and 1 module (that doesn't do it but should).  http://drupal.org/node/213222, Imagefield Extended - http://drupal.org/project/imagefield_extended. Its issue to include a views filter - http://drupal.org/node/107577

Comment: I did some more research, and Imagefield Extended will need to be rewritten to do this.   The data is store in a serialized column in the database.  Serialized data cannot be sorted on.  See this related post for more information http://drupal.org/node/1128270.  Once there is a Drupal 7 release, this should be available for Drupal 7 as the data is no longer serialized.

Comment: Thanks again iStryker. I tried the Imagefield Extended and you are right - it can not be sorted on which is why I guess there is no views filter support. So I had to abandon it. However, I found a solution already in Drupal which I will post as an answer for anyone interested ...